# why the left join failing in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have following views created

```
create view vw_AllCatSpInst    
as    
select 
    s1.InstructionID as ItemID, 
    s1.CatID, s1.Description as ItemName, 
    s2.MainPrice, s2.PriceFor     
from SpecialInstruction s1 left join 
     Prices s2 on s1.InstructionID=s2.SourceID 
where s2.PriceFor=4 and s1.IsDeleted=0    

create view vw_SpInstCustomziation   
as    
    select s1.ProductID, 
           s2.SourceID, 
           s1.IsDefaultDisplay, 
           s1.IsDefault, 
           s1.DefaultFreeCount,  
           s1.CustomCategoryID 
    from dbo.ProductCustomizationMaster s1 inner join 
         ProductCustomizationDetail s2    
         on s1.CustomCategoryID=s2.CategoryID     
         and s1.ProductID=s2.ProductID 
         and s1.IsDefaultDisplay=1 and s1.CustomType=3
```

when i am querying these two views following way it fails the condition  `s1.CatID=@catID` and fetches all left join records.

```
select s1.ItemID, s1.CatID, s2.ProductID, s1.ItemName, s1.MainPrice, s2.IsDefaultDisplay, s2.IsDefault as IsLimited  
from vw_AllCatSpInst s1 left join 
     vw_SpInstCustomziation  s2   
     on  s1.ItemID=s2.SourceID 
     and s1.CatID=s2.CustomCategoryID  
where s1.CatID=@catID 
and   s2.productid=@prodID 
or    s2.productid is null
```

Please help me with this.

Comment: Probably need to add parenthesis in your where clause

Comment: where to add parenthesis in each all views in the end..

Comment: If you say LEFT JOIN and then have a WHERE clause that references the outer table, your outer join becomes an inner join.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you filter on a left joined table in the where clause, your join effectively becomes an inner join.  You have to apply that filter as a join condition.  So this:

```
from vw_AllCatSpInst s1 left join vw_SpInstCustomziation  s2   
on s1.ItemID=s2.SourceID and s1.CatID=s2.CustomCategoryID  
where s1.CatID=@catID and s2.productid=@prodID or s2.productid is null
```

should be:

```
from vw_AllCatSpInst s1 left join vw_SpInstCustomziation  s2   
on s1.ItemID=s2.SourceID and s1.CatID=s2.CustomCategoryID  
and s2.productid=@prodID or s2.productid is null 
where s1.CatID=@catID
```

Actually it should probably be this:

```
from vw_AllCatSpInst s1 left join vw_SpInstCustomziation  s2   
on s1.ItemID=s2.SourceID and s1.CatID=s2.CustomCategoryID  
and 
(
s2.productid=@prodID or s2.productid is null 
)
where s1.CatID=@catID
```

Answer (score 1):

Your first view has this query:

```
select s1.InstructionID as ItemID, 
          s1.CatID, s1.Description as ItemName, 
    s2.MainPrice, s2.PriceFor     
from SpecialInstruction s1 left join 
     Prices s2
     on s1.InstructionID=s2.SourceID 
where s2.PriceFor=4 and s1.IsDeleted=0 ;
```

The where`clause has a condition on`s2.PriceFor`.  This condition does not test of`NULL`.  So, although the`left join`works correctly, the non-matching records have`NULL`values.  To fix this, move the condition on the second table into the`on` clause:

```
select s1.InstructionID as ItemID, 
          s1.CatID, s1.Description as ItemName, 
    s2.MainPrice, s2.PriceFor     
from SpecialInstruction s1 left join 
     Prices s2
     on s1.InstructionID=s2.SourceID and s2.PriceFor=4 
where s1.IsDeleted=0 ;
```

Do not move the condition on `s1` into the `on` clause.